# What do numbers in a crypto algorithm stand for? Is there a convention?

Tags: rsa, aes, sha-256

What do the numbers stand for in the names of cryptographic functions, for example `AES-256`, `RSA-1024` or `SHA-256`?

Do they always refer to key sizes, or is it a different measure for every algorithm?

Is there some convention about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AES-256 and RSA-1024, the numbers refer to the key size. For SHA-256, it refers to the output size. Though there is no hard, fast rule. For example, in the [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances) family, there are hash functions with variable length output, SHAKE128 and SHAKE256. The numbers there refer to the security level.

Then again you have secp256k1, the elliptic curve used, among other places, in BitCoin. It's name [stands for](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=2699.0):

> sec comes from the standard, p means that the curve coordinates are a prime field, 256 means the prime is 256 bits long, k means it is a variant on a so-called Koblitz curve, and 1 means it is the first (and only) curve of that type in the standard.

Then you have hash functions like MD5, which is the 5th version of function designed by Ron Rivest. It's output size is 128 bits. There is also the stream cipher RC4, again by Ron Rivest. There is also an RC2, RC5, and RC6, but I'm not sure where RC1 and RC3 are. :)

From the comments:

> Don't forget SHA-512/224, which is SHA-2 with an internal state of 512 bits and 224 output size, while SHA-224 is SHA-2 with an internal state of 256 bits and an output size of 224 :)

Comment: wow it's quite confusing... thanks for illustrating

Comment: Don't forget SHA-512/224, which is SHA-2 with an internal state of 512 bits and 224 output size, while SHA-224 is SHA-2 with an internal state of 256 bits and an output size of 224 :)

Answer (score 2):

When a crypto algorithm is defined with several variants, these variants usually differ in the value of some parameter $n$ (e.g. key size for block ciphers, output length for hash functions, etc.).  It is then common to denote the variant of the algorithm ALG with parameter value $n$ as "ALG-$n$".  (If there are multiple parameters, you may also see something like "ALG-$m$-$n$" or "ALG-$m$/$n$".)

So, yes, it basically depends on the algorithm, and how it has been defined and standardized.

And yes, it can sometimes get confusing.  A notable example is the [Rijndael](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf) block cipher, which won the NIST AES competition and was standardized as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).  However, whereas the original Rijndael cipher specification included a whole bunch of variants with different key and block sizes (commonly denoted as "Rijndael-$b$/$k$, where $b$ is the block size and $k$ the key size in bits), the AES standard only includes three of these variants, all with a fixed block size of 128 bits, and denotes them as "AES-$k$" where $k$ is the key size.

Thus, AES-128 is the same cipher as Rijndael-128/128, but AES-256 is equivalent to Rijndael-128/256, *not* to Rijndael-256/256 (which, confusingly, is [sometimes called](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/02/aes-php-mcrypt-key-padding/) just Rijndael-256).

All that said, there *are* some common trends, simply because the number of relevant parameters for most types of crypto primitives is limited.  For example, for ciphers, the most relevant parameter is *usually* the key length, while for hash functions it is the output length (which is usually proportional to the internal state size).

Still, plenty of exceptions exist, too.  Off the top of my head, a particularly perverse example is the [Salsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) cipher, where the "20" comes from for the number of rounds the original version of the cipher (a.k.a. Salsa20/20) is applied for, and its later reduced-round variants Salsa20/12 and Salsa20/8, where the "12" and the "8" are the new reduced round counts, and the "20" is basically just a historical naming artifact.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA), the number seems to be completely arbitrary.  It's an implementation of the Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA) using the [elliptic curve 25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519).  The curve is defined by some "magic" numbers:

$$-x^2 + y^2 = 1 - \frac{121665}{121666}x^2y^2$$

over the prime field defined by the prime number $2^{255}-19$.

It appears that the "25519" designation is shorthand for $2^{255}-19$.  Would a larger number than 25519 lead to a stronger cryptosystem?  No, not necessarily.

Comment: It's perhaps worth remarking that Ed25519 (and Curve12219) was developed (and presumably named) by D.J. Bernstein, who's also responsible for the Salsa20 cipher mentioned in my answer, as well as the [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) MAC (where the 1305 similarly stands for $2^{130}-5$). As remarkable a cryptographer as he is, his naming choices do seem to be rather, um, idiosyncratic sometimes.